# Showing UK postcodes on a map

Tags: google-maps

Whats the easiest way to add markers on a map to show locations based on UK postcodes?
I want to show a 'hotspot' type map to show the distribution of the top 100 or so customers.

It does not need to be interactive, just static on a webpage or even printed out. And its a one-off requirement so the simpler the better.

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to process the following database http://www.freepostcodes.org.uk

it will have lat and long in it.

you will need a database and pull the postcodes for the locations you are looking for.

Comment: And then how do I display that on a map?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this is login to Google Maps.

1. Create a new map from My Maps, and save it.
2. Now search for a postcode using the search bar - you will see the post code in a new map below.
3. You can save any search result to any of your saved maps by clicking on the marker and then using the Save to... link to add it to one of your Saved Maps
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 until you've added all your points, then go back to your map (using the My Maps link).  From here you have a number of ways of sharing the map (Print, Link, Send)

Hope that helps...

Comment: Is there any way to upload a CSV file that has all the lat/long data in?

Comment: There's nothing in the Google Maps interface to upload CSV, however the Google Maps API allows you to upload CSV but you would have to get authentication tokens etc. [link](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/mapsdata/developers_guide_protocol.html#uploading_csv).  Originally I thought the problem was Geocoding (converting Postcodes to lat/lng) but if you have the lat/lng then you have the data.  There are a websites that can help with this sort of stuff - GPS Visualizer is a fairly fully features one [link](http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/map_input)